# Change a column of string dates to datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a `varchar` column with 400 entries. Each row is formatted like this:

```
'Thu, 18 Sep 2014 23:59:06 '
```

Is it possible to change this `varchar` column to `datetime`?

I have tried this...

```
ALTER TABLE BE
ALTER COLUMN pubDate datetime
```

But I get the error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: It seems SqlServer does not accept strings with that format as valid dates; IF all strings are of that format, and you are sure data won't be messed, you can try UPDATE TABLE BE SET PubDate=substring(pubDate,6,100) ; first, so you eliminate the 'Thu, ' from all your values, and then try the alter table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a new datetime column, then write an update statement to insert the correct values, then drop the old column (if desired).

The update statement would look something like this:

```
update be set be.dt=convert(datetime, be.pubDate)
```

edit: just about to say the same as okaram in the comments. You probably have to fix your data to be in a format SQL server accepts. Yours is pretty close to 113 if you get rid of the weekday at the beginning and add milliseconds at the end. You need it to look like this:

```
23 Oct 2016 11:02:07:577
```

so

```
update be set be.dt=convert(datetime, 
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(be.pubDate, Charindex(', ', be.pubDate), LEN(be.pubDate)),
':000'), 113)
```

Comment: Hi @Denise I just tried that but still get the eroor Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Dan_JAVA_SQL You probably have other date formats in your date column text, try to standardize them first, even by hand if its only a few...

Answer (score 0):

the correct format for datetime is:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
```

Change your entries and it should work.

Comment: Perhaps changing the entries is what this question boils down to.